# flatten list with repeated element in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have the following data class as a data transfer object.

```
data class Continent(
    val continent: String,
    val countries: List<String>
)
```

so the JSON response is like below.

```
{
  "content": [
       {
           "continent": "Europe",
           "countries": [
              "France",
              "Germany"
           ]
       }
  ]
}
```

However, what I want to do is this:

```
{
  "content": [
        {
            "continent": "Europe",
            "country": "France"
        },
        {
            "continent": "Europe",
            "country": "Germany"
        }
  ]
}
```

I suppose there must be some kotlin collection functions to apply.
Since the dto i wrote in the first code block is unable to be moderated, i have to apply collection functions on the service layer and make response dto accordingly.

Could you please let me know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you do `content.flatMap{it}.distinct()` or `content.flatMap{it}.toSet().toList()`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "repeated" element? In your example all "elements" are distinct. There is only a repeated value of a single property of the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data class Country(
    val continent: String,
    val country: String
)

fun List<ContinentResponse>.toCountries(): List<Country> =
    flatMap { r -> r.countries.map { country -> Country(r.continent, country) } }
```

Comment: what if `r.countries` is an empty list or null and I still want to get it done?